# Multiple media queries on HTML page not working

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to do media queries on an HTML page, but it's not working. Why? Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mq-599.css" media="(min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 599px)">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mq-600-899.css" media="(min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 899px)">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mq-900.css" media="(min-width: 900px)">
</head>
<body>

<h1>I am hotpink at 0 - 599px</h1>
<h1>I am blue at 600px - 899px</h1>
<h1>I am red at 900px or MORE</h1>
<h2>I have a dashed border around me when printed</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

EDIT: Add CSS stylesheets.

mq-599.css

```
h1 {color: hotpink;}
```

mq-600-899.css

```
h1 {color: blue;}
```

mq-900.css

```
h1 {color: red;}
```

EDIT2:

I'm testing this on desktop browser. I'm using Google Chrome 77 on Ubuntu.

Description of the problem:

I want these media queries to load.

The h1 should be hotpink only when it's between 0 - 599px, but it's hotpink in all screen resolutions. The other media queries are not loading.

Comment: You haven't shown us your CSS so how can we possibly know why it isn't working?

Comment: You haven't told us how you are testing this (desktop browser? mobile browser? something else?)

Comment: You've not given a clear description of the problem. What does "not working" mean? Does the Network tab show any of the CSS files being loaded? Are you using a browser which reports CSS errors in the console (if not you should)? What does it say there?

Comment: The network tab does show the CSS files being loaded. I'm not using a browser that shows CSS errors in the console, and I googled about it and couldn't find. Could you recommend one?

Answer (score -3):

I'd address the media queries in the .css files themselves instead of in the link tag. If you want to have different stylesheet files for the different screen sizes, start them with a the media query at the top. For example.

```css
@media (min-width: 900px) {
    h1{
        color: red;
    }
}
```

and the same for your other screen sizes - 600-899 and <599 where you'll write the css rules that you wan't to apply to the corresponding sizes.

[here's a gif with the results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xk2c.gif)